# QtSql correct error handling

Tags: qt

I have some Qt code which works well. But I'm not satisfied how it looks like. This code creates Sqlite database with several tables and some data and if anything goes wrong reports and error and makes a cleanup.

I check by errors this way:

```
if(!query.exec(queryStr))
{
   QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error!"), query.LastError().text());

   // some cleanup here

   this->close();
}
```

There are several issues related to this code. First is that sometimes database driver (Sqlite as I mentioned above) displays its own messageboxes with errors (if errors occur). These messageboxes are not centered and if they were shown (prior to my messagebox with error text) this->close(); does not work. Is there a way how to disable this messageboxes shown by Sqlite driver?

Second issue is that my error handling code looks redundant. With several queries and database connection it looks like this:

```
QSqlDatabase dbase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "newdatabase");
dbase.setDatabaseName(sqlFile);

if (!dbase.open())
{
    // Several lines of error handling
}

QString firstQueryStr = "FIRST SQL QUERY;";
QSqlQuery firstQuery(QSqlDatabase::database("newdatabase"));

if(!firstQuery.exec(firstQueryStr))
{
    // Again that (almost) several lines of error handling
    // as well as new several lines of cleanup
}

QString secondQueryStr = "SECOND QUERY;";
QSqlQuery secondQuery(QSqlDatabase::database("newdatabase"));

if(!secondQuery.exec(secondQueryStr))
{
    // One more time the same lines of error handling
    // as well as the same lines of cleanup
}
```

In c# I would just use try catch and my code would be neat. I haven't found such examples in Qt. I can't put several queries in one because driver does not support it. I can handle these errors by calling own function or (probably) by throwing custom exception but I'm not sure if it is a best way.   What should I do to achieve neat code in Qt in such case? I'm new to Qt and appreciate any help.

Comment: 1) SQLite driver doesn't show any message box, AFAIK - it's not a GUI application 2) If you have a code duplication - implement a function and reuse it instead of repeating `if()` statement.

Comment: Looked in `QSqlDatabase` and `QSQLITE` of Qt, all I can find `qWarnings()`. Can you please add proof to your claim that QSQLITE opens an own QMessageBox. Also, QSqlQuery and database objects need to go out of scope before you can call `removeDatabase`. You don't need to re-declare for each query a new database, you can use the old object.